# How to know the version of the C# using the preprocessor?

Tags: c#, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive, c#-7.3

My project in Debug mode contains constructs that only supports C# 7.3. But in Release mode, the project should be built on C# 7.0 without specific code lines.

I know about some standard preprocessor symbols like `NET472` and `NETSTANDARD2_0` but it uses to work with different standards and their versions. And it useless for language version condition.

```csh
public static Expression<TDelegate> CreateExpression<TDelegate>()
    where TDelegate : Delegate // Work in 7.3 and above
{ ... }
```

I expected some tricks like

```
#if CSharpVersion >= 7.3
   where TDelegate : Delegate
#endif
```

Now I use that statement:

```csh
#if DEBUG
    where TDelegate : Delegate
#endif
```

But it will not work if I change language versions in project properties.

Comment: What is the usecase for having this different compilation process? Why not compile release in 7.3 as well?

Comment: And to answer your question, there's no built in variables for the compiler version. You will have to manage this on your own.

Comment: C# does not have a preprocessor, the #if directive was intentionally crippled to not allow expressions.  Intentionally, they did not want to recreate the C and C++ nightmare.  The pragmatic thing to do is not change the language version.  Or to define "CSharpVersion73" in the project properties so you can make #if work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `DEBUG` define to choose the language version, you can do it in your **.csproj** file:

```
<Project ..>

  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <LangVersion>7.0</LangVersion>
    <LangVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">7.3</LangVersion>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

</Project>
```

Beware that editing the project settings in the UI might changed this.

Comment: What do you mean? VS has already automatically mapped the language version and configuration in .csproj file.
I use `#if DEBUG` to remove a few lines of code in the RELEASE because C#7.3 is only used in debug at the moment. But this trick won't work if I change the configuration settings.

Comment: And, with this, in debug configuration the language version will be 7.3. Otherwise, it will be 7.0. Wasn't that what you wanted?

Comment: thanks. But I was expecting some **preprocessor tricks** that would allow me to work with **any combination** of language version and configuration. For example, using `$"x={x}"` and `String.Format("x={0}", x)` when compiling in versions 6.0(+) and 5.0(-) respectively.

Comment: You can only use one compiler per project.

Comment: I have a suggestion: Why not add `<DefineConstants Condition="'$(LangVersion)' == '7.3'">CS_7_3;...</DefineConstants>` instead? This way, you define your constant in your project when the language version is of a given number. I don't know if this works, I have not tried it myself, but may try in the near future.